# Represent/illustrate communication between two separate programs in UML?

Tags: interface, uml, communication, diagram

Let's say I have an Android app that communicates with a desktop program via Bluetooth sockets.

Pseudo code on Android:

```
class sendToDesktop{
    sendMsg(String msg){
        socket.send(uuid, msg)
    }
}
```

On desktop:

```
class Read{
    getMsg(){
        return socket.read(uuid, msg)
    }
}
```

So how do I represent the relationship between these separate programs in UML? Can I use Component diagrams, or are they only meant to illustrate separate components of a single program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Gangnus points out there are quite many options and none is the one and only.

For example this [websequencediagrams.com script](http://www.websequencediagrams.com/?lz=QW5kcm9pZC0-PnNvY2tldDogc2VuZCh1dWlkLCBtc2cpCkRlc2t0b3AtABgJcmVhZCgpOiBtZXNzYWdlCgAzBi0tPj4AJAc6Cg&s=roundgreen) depicts your scenario:

[image]

The required level of detail (intermediate classes, method names, argument lists...) depends on who will read it and why.

For example this [websequencediagrams.com script](http://www.websequencediagrams.com/?lz=cGFydGljaXBhbnQgQW5kcm9pZAoACAxTZW5kVG9EZXNrdG9wAA0Nc29ja2V0ACANUmVhADAOADAIAFMHLT4AQg06IHNlbmRNc2cobXNnOiBNZXNzYWdlKQoAZw0tPj4AZAYAKAYodXVpZCwgABUcLT4-AIFDBzoKADwJUmVhZDogZ2V0TXNnKCkAZAkKUmVhZC0AWQlyZWFkABMLUGEAgV4FAIFkBi0tPgBABgAuBi0-PgCBPwgK&s=rose) shows also additional internal worker classes:

[image]

See also:

- [uml-diagrams.org: UML Sequence Diagrams](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams.html)

Comment: In case the communication network is, for example, CAN, what would you write instead of this socket? And how can you express the data fields in the msg?

Answer (score 2):

That depends on the level of abstraction. You can use:

- Composite structure diagram (if you want to notice what exactly instances call different services of other applications),
- maybe Timing diagram,
- Sequence diagram(if you are interested in the sequences of mutual calling),
- Interaction overview diagram (messages and timelines are hidden),
- Activity diagram (for analysis of business rules),
- Communication diagram (for naming the pieces of translated information and their addresses),
- and even State or Use Case diagrams.

Try to start from below and continue up to the level where you will have one A4-size diagram.

Comment: @ThomasKilian 1. Also they can be useful for these stages of planning the product, when you check the possibilities of balancing of some threads. 2. The mixing of different UML diagrams could be very useful, but it should be strictly forbidden for the starters. First they should learn the powers and weaknesses of diagrams separately, they should start to think in their terms. If not, the worst fallacy of UML analysis comes - pseudodiagraming - creation of something, that looks like a diagram, but is merely a mishmash of some thoughts.

Comment: @ThomasKilian ad. 2. You are promoting the mix of Sequence and Timing diagrams. I say, that diagrams mixing is very dangerous for starters.

Comment: @ThomasKilian Timing constant and Duration constant cannot help with planning of multithreading with locks.  And those are the only timing features of the SD.

Comment: @ThomasKilian Sorry, but I have said about multithreading in my first comment, in the first sentence. It is a pity, that you have deleted your comments, for obviously, you meant some other timing problems. What have you thought about?

Answer (score 2):

If using UML is imperative, then you may want to consider using a communication diagram as shown [here](http://www.agilemodeling.com/artifacts/communicationDiagram.htm). While a communication diagram is ideally suited for elements of a single application, you can adapt the diagram to show communication from one application to another.

If you are not tied down to UML, I have found data flow diagrams to be very helpful to demonstrate the information that is flowing from one information source/consumer to another (via an intermediary process--in your case the intermediary process might be your methods that contain the Bluetooth logic).

Comment: Which data flow diagram notation do you find useful?

Comment: DeMarco, Yourdon, et al. My organization uses DFD's quite a bit; primarily to diagram information flows in business processes, but I have also used a simplified version of them to communicate to stakeholders detailed concepts as well.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to the original question: no, component diagrams are not restricted to parts of a single program so yes, you can use them.

UML diagrams are not tailored to any specific level of abstraction or scope of work. If your "system under consideration" contains two programs, then that's what you should show in the diagram.